# Kafka producer.send() is Stopped by producer.close()

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to send the output of a word-count problem (in spark- scala) on a kafka topic named "test". See Below Code:

```
val Dstream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)

val lines = Dstream.map(f => f._2)
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

wordCounts.foreachRDD(
      rdd => rdd.foreach(
        f =>
          {
            val sendProps = new Properties()
            sendProps.put("metadata.broker.list", brokers)
            sendProps.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder")
            sendProps.put("producer.type", "async")

            val config = new ProducerConfig(sendProps)
            val producer = new Producer[String, String](config)
            producer.send(new KeyedMessage[String, String]"test", f._1 + " " +f._2))
            producer.close();

          }))
```

The problem is some words are missing in output randomly. I also noticed that if I removed the statement

```
producer.close()
```

there is no data loss.

Does this mean *producer.close()* interrupts *producer.send()* before it actually puts data in buffer due to which that particular tuple is not being sent to consumer? If Yes, How shall I close producer without risking data loss?

**Above was my initial problem and solved by Vale's answer.**

Now, when I change *producer.type* property again - data goes missing randomly.

```
sendProps.put("producer.type", "sync")
```

To clarify *producer.send* is running for all the words I need to put in output Topic. But, some words go missing and are not displayed in output Kafka Topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is weird. The close() method should wait for the send to have finished, and this was why a close(time) method was introduced: [as you can see here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-15+-+Add+a+close+method+with+a+timeout+in+the+producer).
So, I use Java 7. Is the rdd.foreach operating on each partition inside it? Or is it operating on each Tuple (as I think it's doing)?
If the latter, could you try a rdd.foreachPartition ([refer to this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams))? Because you are creating a producer for each line you take, and I fear this could be causing problems (although theoretically it shouldn't).

Comment: I am actually reading data from a kafka stream. And Yes, A new producer is being created for every tuple. Please tell me what to try after you see this.

Comment: I know you're using the DStreams. I can't write in scala yet. If you look at my refer to this link there is a "how to use foreachRDD" which suggests you this kind of structure:  

`dstream.foreachRDD  
            |-rdd.foreachPartition  
                           |-create new producer, get stuff from partition and send it`

Comment: Thanks Vale. The solution worked perfectly fine. I had been banging my head for more than a day. You saved my soul.

Comment: @CodeSanta did it work? Edit: glad to know! It actually is my first answer =)

Comment: Although the program is now working fine when it runs and picks data that is already lying in that topic; I am still facing problem when I am trying to write data to kafka topic (from where i am taking my input) while the job is running. Any idea why so?

Comment: I apologize: could you reformulate the question? You have problems writing in the topic from (where I am taking my input = another topic? ) while the partition is being processed? Correct? 
What kind of problem? Missing data? Have you got any .filter in there?

Comment: I suggest you to make a new question, because I do not know the answer to this issue. If you find out, let me know. I'm sure this will interest me as well